# How do I trim a csv in Matlab, like I could in bash, in order to load the csv with Matlab's readtable?

Tags: bash, matlab, csv, sed

The `csv` that needs to be analysed contains a useless label in the first row.

The headers are located in the second row.

Other useless information from line 102 and on, which totals to 147 lines of uselessness, which contain a different number of columns than the 100 rows above it.

The relavent rows contain numeric values as well as the occasional `NaN`.
When the `csv` is opened, it would resemble:

```
unnecessarily labeled
columnA     columnB     columnC    columnD     columnE
1           2           3          4           5
4           5           6          NaN           8
[...]
301         302         303        304         305
data        that        really     belongs     in       a     separate     csv
```

`csv sample`

```
unnecessarily labeled,,,,,,,,
columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD,columnE,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,,,,
4,5,6,NaN,8,,,,
301,302,303,304,305,,,,
data,that,really,belongs,in,a,separate,csv,
```

If I were to pre-process the file in bash I would:

```
sed -e1,1d $f > $processedFilename #remove the top line
head -n -147 $processedFilename > tmp && mv tmp $processedFilename  #remove the last 147 lines
```

Can I do a similar pre-processing in Matlab?  Can this be done more directly with `readtable` ?  In other words, how can I load this `csv` data into a table preferably with the benefits of the headers populating automagically and with only the relevant rows and columns? In other other words, is there a parallel [to](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#buggjy1-6)

`T = readtable('patients.xls',...
    'Range','C2:E6',...`

for `csv` data?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct method in Matlab to skip lines at the end of a file, so really the most you can do is read all of the data, then delete the extraneous rows/columns.

We can specify the number of lines to skip at the beginning of the file by passing 'HeaderLines', though.

I imagine you want a method that works in the general case with files of this format; However, if you know at least how many columns of data there will be, and how many extraneous lines there will be at the end, then this should work:

```
x = readtable('file', 'HeaderLines', 1);
x = x(:, 1:num_columns);
headers = table2cell(x(1, :));
x.Properties.VariableNames = headers;
x = x(2:size(x, 1) - num_extraneous_rows, :);
```

First, we manually pick the number of columns to include.
Then, we set the headers of the table.
Finally, we exclude the extraneous rows (and the first row containing the headers).

Comment: Using the sample data provided above: >> x=readtable('csvSample.csv', 'HeaderLines', 1);
Error using readtable (line 129)
The data in this file does not appear to be tabular, with the same number of fields in
each row and in each column. You might need to specify or modify the delimiter or number
of header lines.

Comment: the error above was identical both before and after the addition of a missing a comma on the first line

Comment: That's odd... What version of Matlab are you using? I'm on 2016a, and on your file, with num_columns = 5 and num_extraneous_rows = 1, I'm not getting any issues...

http://puu.sh/qnnBE/417d53e90a.png

Comment: 2014b.  Although, tomorrow I plan to update to 2016a.  Nonetheless, it will still be relevant to be backwards compatible.

Comment: I can confirm that your code does not error in Matlab 2016a, and errors in 2014b.

Comment: I suppose if you want something that's compatible with previous versions, you'd have to manually specify the format of your data via textscan or some similar method...

The code I posted above was the most direct method that comes to mind.